# Combine Voice Memos in iOS

Tags: ios, voice-memo

Is there a way to combine two or more Voice Memos into **one recording**?

I would be willing to use some software.

I tried to duplicate the recording but found no way of combing the two toegether.

---

iOS 12 on iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

The native Voice Memos.app doesn’t offer this. You will need to upload your recording to a computer and use a audio editing application like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/) I’m not affiliated with the software.

> iTunes does not have a way to do that.  You can do it with an audio editor.  A free one that many people like, and which has Mac and Windows versions, is Audacity.

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4707813